# R package RSiena, goodness of fit for multiple networks at the same time

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R and I'm running network and behavior coevolution models using the R Package RSiena. 
My data set consists of around 100 networks and for each of these networks, I run one RSiena model.

```
ans.1 <- siena07(myalgorithm, data=mydata.1, effects=myeff.1, batch=TRUE)
...
ans.100 <- siena07(myalgorithm, data=mydata.100, effects=myeff.100, batch=TRUE)
```

Now I want to test the goodness of fit for each of the multiple network models. I actually know how to check the goodness of fit for a single model.

```
gof <- sienaGOF(ans.1, verbose=TRUE, varName="Friend", IndegreeDistribution)
plot(gof)
```

But I don't know how to combine the GOF results of all 100 models to get an overall impression. How can I get a table with the model number and the p-values. Or can I plot the results for all models within one plot? Or is there a better way?

So far I tried to put the GOF results in a list:

```
goftest <-list()
goftest[[1]] <- sienaGOF(ans.1, verbose=TRUE, varName="Friend", IndegreeDistribution)
...
goftest[[100]] <- sienaGOF(ans.100, verbose=TRUE, varName="Friend", IndegreeDistribution)

plot(goftest)
goftest[[1]] #Output:

"Siena Goodness of Fit ( IndegreeDistribution ), all periods
=====
Monte Carlo Mahalanobis distance test p-value:  0.941 
-----
One tailed test used  (i.e. estimated probability of greater distance than observation).
-----
Calculated joint MHD = ( 14.4 ) for current model."

str(goftest[[1]])#Output:

"List of 1
 $ Joint:List of 8
  ..$ p                : num 0.941
  ..$ SimulatedTestStat: Named num [1:2000] 9.97 16.02 6.83 10.14 8.65 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2000] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ ObservedTestStat : num 2.09
  ..$ TwoTailed        : logi FALSE
  ..$ Simulations      : int [1:2000, 1:9] 21 22 22 21 19 26 30 23 25 26 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2000] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  ..$ Observations     : int [1, 1:9] 26 48 63 73 76 78 78 78 78
  ..$ InvCovSimStats   : num [1:9, 1:9] 13.2509 4.9587 1.2948 0.231 0.0895 ...
  ..$ Rank             : int 9
  .. ..- attr(*, "method")= chr "tolNorm2"
  .. ..- attr(*, "useGrad")= logi FALSE
  .. ..- attr(*, "tol")= num 2e-15
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "sienaGofTest"
  ..- attr(*, "sienaFitName")= chr "sienaFitObject"
  ..- attr(*, "auxiliaryStatisticName")= chr "IndegreeDistribution"
  ..- attr(*, "key")= chr [1:9] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "sienaGOF"
 - attr(*, "scoreTest")= logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "originalMahalanobisDistances")= num [1:3] 2.15 3.51 8.74
 - attr(*, "oneStepMahalanobisDistances")=List of 3
  ..$ : Named num(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr(0) 
  ..$ : Named num(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr(0) 
  ..$ : Named num(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr(0) 
 - attr(*, "joinedOneStepMahalanobisDistances")= Named num(0) 
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr(0) 
 - attr(*, "oneStepMahalanobisDistances_old")=List of 3
  ..$ : Named num(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr(0) 
  ..$ : Named num(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr(0) 
  ..$ : Named num(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr(0) 
 - attr(*, "joinedOneStepMahalanobisDistances_old")= Named num(0) 
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr(0) 
 - attr(*, "oneStepSpecs")= num[1:20, 0 ] 
 - attr(*, "auxiliaryStatisticName")= chr "IndegreeDistribution"
 - attr(*, "simTime")= 'proc_time' Named num [1:5] 39.61 0.28 40.21 NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "user.self" "sys.self" "elapsed" "user.child" ...
 - attr(*, "twoTailed")= logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "joined")= logi TRUE"
```

But I don't know how to extract the p-Values and get a table, which just contains the network number and the associated p-value. 
Furthermore, the plot command just produces error messages and no output so far.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO ! Have you considered using [lists](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_lists.htm) ? Both for your repetitive process of model generation and the plotting down the line, this can be incredibly helpful. As for your plotting question, you would have to get the relevant data from the output of  `sienaGOF` and plot that yourself (*e.g* iteratively with your list).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply! I tried to include lists now (see above), but I don't know how to extract the specific information I need from the list. Do you have suggestions?

Comment: I would need to know what's in the output of `sienaGOF` for that. can you add some data to your post ? You can do this by pasting the output of `dput(myobject)`.

Comment: Above you can find the output for `sienaGOF`. The Output for `dput(goftest[[1]])` is unfortunately to long for the character limit at StackOverflow.. Furthermore I can not find the p-value in it.

Comment: Then you can take a look at `str(goftest[[1]])`

Comment: I updated my post and added the output for `str(goftest[[1]])`. I tried to retrieve the p-value with `goftest[[1]]$p` - however, I only get the output "NULL".

Comment: Yes, you need to do `goftest[[1]][[1]]$p`. The first line of the str output says it's a "List of 1"